# Getting Google Play services signature invalid

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate Google plus login in my application, I am following this guide for the same: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

Everything is setup properly except when I run the application I get the "Google Play services signature invalid"

I think the problem is in the SHA1 key I am generating, however I have done it as it has been described in the above document. I am unable to gauge the problem. Any hints?

I am also attaching the screen shot of how I generated the key: http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/3039/d96d.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your debug key, have you associated it with your build?

In the pic below, from Window->Preferences, and then Android->Build, whichever key  is using your SHA1 that starts with F2:38, needs to be the selected key to build with...

(keep this key if for when you want to re-install, change to another computer.. etc...)

[image]

If that isn't it, a couple of other things pop to mind.

Make sure your package name matches with whatever package you added on your developer account, and make sure you are only using the number portion in your ID resource file:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_id">774883601790</string>
</resources>
```

and of course that the account you are trying is your developer account, or added to your list of test accounts (wouldn't be the same error though...)

Comment: Thanks mate, let me try this.