# Google Play Services Invalid

Tags: android

To give a bit of context for my problem, I recently ran into errors with all my developed applications that were using google play services, giving classnotfound exceptions despite them working before.

I saw that there was an update available for google play services so decided to install it, but now all my developed apps are throwing a "google play services signature invalid" error. When the apps are run on my phone a pop-up appears telling me that "google play services is not available on this device..."

I can't seem to find much on this error when looking it up and am very confused as to what the root of the problem is. I have tried deleting and re-importing the google-play-services library but that has not helped help, and I see from the eclipse console that google-play-services.apk is being installed successfully on my device.

I am getting this error even from the android tutorial apps.

If anybody has a shred of knowledge on this problem I would be appreciative.

**EDIT:** I should also mention that after I updated google play services, I was prompted to include the following tag in my manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I found this strange as I never needed it before.

Logcat Output

```
11-04 17:42:36.068: I/ApplicationPackageManager(4433): cscCountry is not German : O2I
11-04 17:42:36.107: D/dalvikvm(4433): DexOpt: couldn't find field   Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
11-04 17:42:36.107: W/dalvikvm(4433): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 35
11-04 17:42:36.107: D/dalvikvm(4433): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
11-04 17:42:36.107: D/dalvikvm(4433): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in  Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
11-04 17:42:36.154: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4433): Google Play services signature invalid.
11-04 17:42:36.154: D/result(4433): SERVICE_INVALID
11-04 17:42:36.186: I/System.out(4433): false
11-04 17:42:36.186: I/System.out(4433): false
11-04 17:42:36.186: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4433): Google Play services signature    invalid.
11-04 17:42:36.201: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4433): Google Play services is invalid. Cannot recover.
```

**EDIT 2:** I ran my app on my mums phone, it gave an error saying that google play services needed to be updated on the phone, there was no new version available so instead I used the froyo version of google play services as it is rev 12. This actually worked, but I'm still at a total loss as to what is going on in my phone and why the service is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I appeared to have fixed although it was not very pretty, for some strange reason there never seemed to be Google play services actually installed on my phone, I have no idea how my apps ever worked previously. I went into my applications and uninstalled com.google.android.gms, then when my app was ran again instead of telling me that Google play services was not supported, it gave  a link to download Google play services, once I installed it it seemed to work correctly.

I should add that this is all using the froyo version of google play services (rev 12). If I use the latest version of google play services (rev 13) I am prompted to update but find no update available in google play store, I assume this is because the update has not found its way to the market, as this version was only been released 3 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

What usually helps for me if I run into problems like that is

1. to go to my project build path
2. configure build path
3. click the order and export tab
4. check the Android private libraries checkbox

After just do a clean and build.

Give it a try, hope it helps

Comment: Yes I have given this a try (and just gave it another for good measure) but it does not seem to be digging me out of this hole this time.

Comment: What are you using the play services for btw?

Comment: Originally it was to implement an app that could use geofencing, but now it is me just trying to get the android location tutorials working.

Comment: can you give the stack? or just the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I've added the Logcat output. The part where things start to look bad is:   **W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4433): Google Play services signature      invalid.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4433): Google Play services is invalid.  Cannot recover.**

Comment: Have a look at this. Maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178079/getting-google-play-services-signature-invalid